# How to divide project hours over project length with a known end date in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, forecasting

I'm trying to figure out how to spread the estimated hours for a project over the length of that project with a known end date.

Example, I have Project 001, it is 600 hours, and it is a six-month project that is due to release June 2020.  Each of these values (project identifier, hours, length, and release date) are separate columns in a database.

In this example, Project 001 would add 100 hours to each month from January to June.  If Project 002 had 300 hours with the same length and release date, now each month would have 150 hours.

The end goal is to get a forecast of how many hours we expect in each month for all the projects we have to determine the overall capacity demands for the month.  So we'd have something like a bar chart that shows the total hours demand for each month based on the projects that will impact that month.  Or we'd have a bar chart that shows the remaining capacity (fixed monthly capacity minus monthly estimated hours).

I haven't been able to determine how to generate something that will divide the hours backward over the length of the project based on the project end date.  I'm still pretty new to Power BI, so I could do with some guidance on this one.  I'm well versed in Excel and VBA, I understand the basics of creating measures and some of the ways Power BI "formulas" are written.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of your input and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

I made a small test table:
[image]
I added the column: HoursPerDay

```
HoursPerDay = Hours[Hours]/ DATEDIFF(Hours[StartDate];Hours[EndDate];DAY)
```

Next I made a calendar table:

```
Calendar = CALENDAR(MIN(Hours[StartDate]);MAX(Hours[EndDate]))
```

I added the measure HoursPerProject to this table:

```
HoursPerProject = CALCULATE(SUM(Hours[HoursPerDay]);FILTER(Hours;Hours[StartDate] <= VALUES('Calendar'[Date]) && Hours[EndDate] >= VALUES('Calendar'[Date])))
```

This is the important bit because it checks if it should include the hours for a prject on that day.

When putting this in a stacked column graph, you need to place the HoursPerProject in the value and the Date of calendar on the Axis. Hope this helps you.

[image]